Domain will not transfer to surge
I am having issue with transferring my domain name to surge. I have followed the surge instructions to add the CNAME:
na-west1.surge.sh

and also the DNS 45.55.110.124 but when i type my domain in i get the surge logo with project not found.
I have contacted the domain company and they have added the details. I am not sure if my package.json needs amending, this is what i have.
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "npm run build && surge ./build/ portfolio.surge.sh"
  },

